# Bypass wifi confirmation screens

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, wifi

I have a raspberry Pi that'd I like to use to connect to wifi networks for which I've already configured to connect to. However, on one wifi network I'd like to connect to, it brings up a window in a browser that has a terms and conditions that you have to accept. How to bypass, as id prefer not to have to hook it up to a display?

Also, sorry ahead of time about my inferior lack of network, but I believe my school's student wifi uses "trust certificates" (?). I remember getting my iPhone on the network and having to use not only a username and a password, but I had to "accept" a trust certificate. Can I perform those actions via command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `curl` command to detect and deactivate the captive portal from a shell script. Details will vary from portal to portal but running `curl http://example.com` when connected to the network with the captive portal will get you started.

Regarding your school's Wi-Fi, it's very likely using 802.1X authentication, which uses Certificates for security, see: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23079/how-to-connect-to-802-1x-eap-wireless-network-with-debian-wheezy

Answer (score 0):

I found great help with this on this guide https://frankiejarrett.com/2014/09/how-to-connect-apple-tv-to-a-hotel-wi-fi-network . It is for an appletv but works same for raspberrypi. Basically you spoof your MAC address on your computer, connect to wifi and agree to terms and conditions and then change your computer's MAC address back to your original and then connect your raspberrypi to the wifi.